# Why does input.value in my javascript always return an empty string?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a list of numbers from an input field in a very simple number pair counting program. I cannot get any value from my input field - no matter what input I give it console logs "". I'm sure it's an easy tweak I'm missing.
The problem line is in handleSearch(): const searchList = input.value;
countPairs is a function taking an int and an array and returning an int

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<h1 style="color:indigo">Let's Count Pairs of Socks!</h1>
<h3 style="color:indigo">Enter a list of number socks:</h3>
<div id=Lisa></div>
`;
const input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("placeholder", "22, 22, 33");
const Lisa = document.getElementById("Lisa");
Lisa.appendChild(input);
const button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerText = "Get number of pairs!";
button.style.color = "indigo";
Lisa.innerHTML += `<br><br>`;
Lisa.appendChild(button);
const results = document.createElement("div");
Lisa.appendChild(results);
const handleSearch = () => {
  const searchList = input.value;
  console.log(input.value);
  const numPairs = countPairs(searchList.length, searchList);
  const title = document.createElement("h3");
  title.innerText = "The number of pairs is.....";
  title.style.color = "indigo";
  const pairs = document.createElement("h4");
  pairs.innerText = numPairs;
  pairs.style.color = "indigo";
  Lisa.innerHTML += `<br><br>`;
  Lisa.appendChild(title);
  Lisa.appendChild(pairs);
};
button.addEventListener("click", handleSearch);
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: What's your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
someElement.innerHTML +=
```

This is equivalent to

```
someElement.innerHTML = someElement.innerHTML + ...
```

In other words, *all the children* get re-parsed according to the new HTML that was set.

If you previously created an element with `createElement` and put it as a child, if you do `.innerHTML +=` on the parent, the created element will no longer be connected to the DOM - instead, a new element with the same HTML markup will be there instead. So, your `input.value` will be showing you the value of the input that's no longer there.

Change both occurrences of

```
Lisa.innerHTML += `<br><br>`;
```

to

```
Lisa.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<br><br>`);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch CertainPerformance for explaining that! Works perfectly now and I understand what happened ;)

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you can consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox next to the answer) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)